# Partition function of a QFT.

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

There is a YouTube lecture by Robert Dijkgraaf titled:"Introduction to Topological and Conformal Field Theory (1 of 2)."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEEQO-tcyHc&t=2977s

At one point he obtains partition function by taking usual trace but before that he also defines it as a function that takes closed manifolds as input and a complex number as output. In fact, this is how Dan Freed also defines the partition funtion.

https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/CBMS133.pdf

I am a bit confused since taking trace only gives a Tori and that is what appear on N-lab.

They are defining it for a general n-dimensional theories (if I haven't misunderstood). There is no such classification therorem in dimension greater than 2 that can tell us that all closed n-manifolds (other than spheres) can be obtained by gluing two ends.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  A partition function is defined on the moduli stack of closed n-manifolds.  In the case when a closed n-manifold M is obtained by gluing together the two ends of a bordism N, the definition of a functorial field theory implies that the value on M is the trace of the value on N.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez My apologies. I just added the link. It is around 21:12 in Robert's Lecture and on page-17 in Dan's book.

Comment: @DmitriP.  But that's not how it is defined in the Physics texts. Let's for example Nakahara in Geometry, Topology, and Physics section 1.3.2 (1.110) defines partition function for a Wick-rotated QFT as taking trace which amounts to gluing two ends of n+1 cylinder M x [0,1]. It looks to me that this definition is a special case of partition  function defined by both Dijkgraaf and Freed since in dimension greater than 2, not all closed manifolds can be obtained this way. Here I am trying to use the idea Dijkgraaf mentions around 27:00 in the above video.

Comment: @DmitriP. ... Usually when I talk to Physicists it becomes an issue. So, I wanted to confirm how exactly is a partition function of a QFT is defined. Also, can I know a reference for the definition you gave using moduli-stack? It is very intriguing to me.

Comment: @NikhileshBairagi: Already in the two-dimensional case, the partition function is defined on the moduli stack of surfaces of an arbitrary genus g, not just genus 1 (corresponding to tori / cylinders).  See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9204083v1, formula (1.10).

Comment: @DmitriP. Thank you sir! I look forward to skim it (at least.)